# Помогите сделать правильное условие

Tags: php

Хочу сделать так:

```
if (пятница) {//условие};
```

Тоесть как определить пятницу кодом)

Comment: Люблю такие вопросы. А что мешает так сделать?

Comment: Благословляю...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Например так:

```
if (5 == date('w')) {
    drinkVodka();
}
```

См. также [date](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php), [strftime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strftime.php), [getdate](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.getdate.php)

Comment: правильное условие)

Comment: А `if (5 == date('w')) { drinkVodka();
}` только до 13:20 часов дня и в `else { //условие еще }` Как такое сделать?)

Comment: @pwnz22 Что же вы по ссылкам не прошлись. Например `getdate` возвращает структуру, в которой и часы и минуты есть, дальше можно сравнивать как угодно. Можно взять время в виде `date('Hi')` и сравнить его с числом `1320`

Answer (score 1):

Грубо говоря:

```
$daysOfWeek = array('monday' => 1, 'tuesday' => 2, 'wednesday' => 3, 'thursday' => 4, 'friday' => 5, 'saturday' => 6, 'sunday' => 7);

if (date('w') == $daysOfWeek['friday']) {
// some code
}
```

Т.е. нужно завести переменную, или константы, или функцию, которая будет возвращать день недели, а потом сравнить текущую дату с тем, что в переменной/константе/результате функции. И если условие верно - выполнить код